# Singleton Design "not being able to resolve to a type"

Tags: java, singleton

I'm trying to instantiate the Scanner using the Singleton design, but when I try to get my main method to instantiate the Scanner, I get an error saying that "Singleton.getInstance() can't be resolved to a type.

```
package exercise;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NestedLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        stars();
        numbs();
}

public static void stars() {

    Singleton scanner=new Singleton.getInstance();
    int input=scanner.intScan();
    
    for(int row=0;row<input;row++) {
        for(int column=0;column<6;column++) {
        System.out.print("*");
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(scanner));
}

public static void numbs() {
    Singleton scanner=new Singleton.getInstance();
    int input=scanner.intScan();
    for(int row=0;row<input;row++) {
        for(int column=0;column<=row;column++) {
            System.out.printf("%d ",column+1);
        }
    System.out.println();   
    }
    scanner.closeScan();
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(scanner));
}
}
```

As for the Singleton class:

```
package exercise;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Singleton {
    
    private static Singleton callScan=null;
    private Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    private Singleton(){};
    
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if(callScan==null) {
            callScan=new Singleton();
        }
        return callScan;
    }
    
    public int intScan() {
        int val= input.nextInt();
        return val;
    }
    
    public void closeScan() {
        input.close();
    }

}
```

Kind of stumped! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Singleton scanner = new Singleton.getInstance();
```

with

```
Singleton scanner = Singleton.getInstance(); // Singleton.getInstance() is already an instance.
```

Comment: I suggest you add a mention that you are dropping the `new`, to make your point obvious.